# error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

getting the error

> error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

string to be replaced

> newDate = "/Date(1430370000000+0530)/"

Code

```
newDate.Replace("/","\/")
```

I am trying to replace a backslash

> /

with forward and backward slash

```
\/
```

Comment: the exact same question as yesterday...

Comment: the question above is not at all a duplicate, issue here it is different ... I still not got a solution from the duplicated question

Comment: a wooden hammer method is `newdate = $"\\/{newDate.Trim('/','\')}\\/";`

Comment: is this c# code???

Comment: @tom Not sure how i execute it in C#

Comment: yes, its a c# inline string format. An equivalent in multiple lines: `var tmp = newDate.Trim('/','\');` `newdate = string.Format("\\/{0}\\/", tmp);`

Comment: str = $"\\/{str.Trim('/','\')}\\/"    gives Unexpected character '$'

Comment: http://rextester.com/MAB71989

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153865/discussion-between-tom-schardt-and-smartestvega).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
newDate.Replace("/","\\/")
```

as \ has special meaning and you used it improperly causing the quoted error. See [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for more details.

Alternatively try [verbatim literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) using @-quoting:

```
newDate.Replace("/", @"\/")
```

Comment: i m getting "\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/"  but i just want "\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\/"

Comment: one slash extra added

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: still i am getting the same "\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/"  i dont need tw o froward slash after quote , i just need one

Comment: Then I strongly doubt real `newDate` value is as you shown in the question. you can try replacing wiht i.e. `XY` instead to see what will be the output.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: as long as you watch the result in the debugger you will see the escaped version: backslash will be displayed as backslash backslash. The reason is that a single backslash inside string begins an escape sequence. By the way: / is a slash while \ is called backslash.

Comment: You mean it's okay to leave it like that?

Comment: You should display the variable value using i.e. `Console.WriteLine()` to verify my solutions works (both :)

Comment: see this http://rextester.com/XRYHVO38997

Comment: your code from the above link makes complete no sense, esp. `Replace()` makes **no change** at all so the output is **correct** for what you have there. Do you understand what you are doing?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski good point, it should be `newDate = newDate.Replace("/","\\/")` to make a difference

Comment: i got "\\/Date(1430370000000+0530)\\/" again so No luck

Comment: please post your complete code sequence to make sure there are no other errors avoid functionatily